# Ektron CMS not saving image alt text?

Tags: ektron

At our university, we use Ektron CMS 8.02 SP2 and we are trying to bring our site up to 508 compliance.

The editor does not save the image alt text in the xml after clicking the publish button. This is causing a problem on our site because we must have image alt text for all of our images on the site. For now, the alt text is defaulting to the image source, but even that is not being stored in the xml for the individual pages that we need to add the text to.

Is there anything we can do to resolve this?

Things I have tried:

1. Looking on Ektron's guide to using their (defunct) system.
2. Asking this question.

If at all possible, I would like to avoid editing the xml template, but if that is the only way to fix this, then let me know.

The purpose of this question is to find alternative ways to do this without editing the xml template.

Comment: Is this structured content (e.g. SmartForm content)? Or unstructured content (HTML / wysiwyg content)? Given you mentioned XML, I'm assuming SmartForm structured content. Are you using an Image Only field? We just tried this on 8.02 SP5 and SP3; the Image Only field contains an alt attribute by default when I insert the image from the library. Would be helpful if you could post more details.

Comment: We are using structured content (SmartForms) and the templates use Image Only fields. When I click the image icon, the dialogue pops up with fields for Border, Alt Text, Alignment, Source, Spacing, and dimensions. The Alt Text is autofilled with the image source field. When the Alt Text is edited, it isn't saved and the next time the page is edited the Alt Text has the image source in it again. I looked at the XML for the page and there is no field for Alt Text in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image field in a Smart Form can be configured two ways.

**Option 1:** Value is an element

```
<FieldName>
    <img src="{path}" alt="{text}" />
</FieldName>
```

In this case, the Image attributes are preserved.

**Option 2:** Value is plain text

```
<FieldName>{path}</FieldName>
```

In this case, only the path is stored as a plain text string.

Based on your description, I'd guess you're using Option 2 when you want Option 1.

See red outlined area here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ektron Support for not telling me this when I emailed and called 5 times...